# Visual Studio Code quick fix import not working in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, import, intellisense

I have installed various extensions in Visual Studio Code for being able to import through auto suggestion or auto-import when I paste some code, but it still doesn't work.

[image]

Extensions:

```
npm
npm intellisense
material-ui snippets
JS snippets
ESLint
ES7 React/Redux/GraphQLetc. snippets
and other varios exntensions.
```

I also want to mention that the language mode is set to JavaScript React.

How it would be possible to have something similar as this from WebStorm?
[image]

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Hi @MohammadNorhamizan unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

About this problem, I've done a lot of research because my .net application on vscode didnt give me any quick tips. I've seen some people solved it by reinstalling extensions they use. And some solved by reinstalling vscode again. And some of us we just restarted vscode and problem is gone.